# Using rho mobile, the following error occurs concerning the build.yml

Tags: java

Could not open the editor: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List

What do I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post code where you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`String` class represents character strings. Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created.

`List` is an interface, which provides implementation to have elements in indexed based list. Elements can be accessed using integer index.

`String` and `List` are both objects but are of different types.
So there is no possibility  to cast `String` to `List`.

References:

- [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
- [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)